# Struts2 form with two buttons -- action not being processed correctly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I've tried searching the forums for the answer to this, and I've been unsuccessful.  I have a Struts2 form with two buttons, and I want the action class to perform a different action depending on which button was pressed.  That's not happening.  Can anyone help me with this?  Here is my form, followed by the action class.

```
    <s:form action="ApproveBulletin" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><b>From:</b> <s:property value="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><b>Subject:</b> <s:property value="subject" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><b>Date:</b> <s:property value="date" /> <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><s:property value="note" />
                    <s:hidden name="id" value="%{id}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><s:submit type="button" name="approve" value="approve" label="Approve" /></td>
                <td><s:submit type="button" name="deny" value="deny" label="Deny" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
    </s:form>

public String execute() {
    BulletinDAO bulletinDAOInstance = new BulletinDAO();

    if ("Approve".equals(buttonName)) {
        if (bulletinDAOInstance.approveBulletin(id) == true) {
            return "redirect";
        }           
    }

    if ("Deny".equals(buttonName)) {
        if (bulletinDAOInstance.denyBulletin(id) == true) {
            return "redirect";
        }                       
    }

    return "failure";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the action code of the solution I came up with.

```
    BulletinDAO bulletinDAOInstance = new BulletinDAO();

    if (approve != null) {
        if (bulletinDAOInstance.approveBulletin(id) == true) {
            HttpSession session = (HttpSession) request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("confirmation",
                    "Your bulletin has been approved.");
            return "success";
        }
    }

    if (deny != null) {
        if (bulletinDAOInstance.denyBulletin(id) == true) {
            HttpSession session = (HttpSession) request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("confirmation",
                    "Your bulletin has been denied.");
            return "success";
        }
    }

    return "failure";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have 2 different actions in the "struts.xml" file for the 2 buttons.
In jsp, you can set the form action for the corresponding button through javascript.

**On Jsp:**

For "Approve Button" set action as "ApproveAction", for "Deny Button" set action as "DenyAction" through javascript

**Sample Struts.xml**

```
....
<action name="ApproveAction" class="com.package.YourActionClass" method="approve">
<result>/pages/Approve.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="DenyAction" class="com.package.YourActionClass" method="deny">
<result>/pages/Deny.jsp</result>
</action>
...
```

In "YourActionClass", you can then write your code in two different method i.e "approve" and "deny".

Comment: I think I've discovered another way to do this without the JavaScript, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Hey, can u share that other way?